# boost::bind doesn't work with boost::tuple::get<N>()

Tags: c++, stl, boost-bind, boost-tuples

I am trying to use `boost::bind` and STL with `boost::tuple`, but each time I try to compile I get the following error.

```
      error: call of overloaded ‘bind(<unresolved overloaded function type>, 
      boost::arg<1>&)’ is ambiguous
```

Do you know what I am doing wrong here and why is only for the `boost::arg<1>`?

Thanks
AFG

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <vector>
    #include <cstdio>
    #include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
    #include <boost/assign.hpp>
    #include <boost/bind.hpp>

    int main( int argc, const char** argv ){


            using namespace boost::assign;
            typedef boost::tuple< int, double > eth_array;

            std::vector< eth_array > v;
            v+= boost::make_tuple( 10,23.4), boost::make_tuple( 12,24.4) );
            std::for_each( v.begin()
                    , v.end()
                    , boost::bind<int>(
                            printf
                            , "%d-%f"
                            , boost::bind( eth_array::get<0>, _1 )
                            , boost::bind( eth_array::get<1>, _1 )
                     )
            );
```

Comment: What is an `eth_array`? Isn't `get` something in the `boost` namespace? Not this `eth_array` namespace/class?

Comment: auch ..I have changed while copying the code. Fixed in the above sample.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `get` function has more than one template parameter: in addition to the index, it is also parameterized on the content of the tuple (the head and the tail of the `cons`).

Consequently, `get<0>` is not an instantiation of the template; you need to provide the additional arguments:

```
typedef eth_array::head_type head;
typedef eth_array::tail_type tail;

... get<0, head, tail> ...
```

However, this still won't work because `get` is overloaded (const and non-const version), so you need to explicitely state which overload you want. To do so, you need to use a function pointer with the correct type:

```
// const version of get, which takes and returns const references
int const & (*get0)( boost::tuples::cons<head, tail> const & ) = 
    boost::get<0, head, tail>;
double const & (*get1)( boost::tuples::cons<head, tail> const & ) = 
    boost::get<1, head, tail>;
```

Now you can use these function pointers in your bind expression:

```
std::for_each( v.begin(),
               v.end(),
               boost::bind<int>(
                   printf,
                   "%d-%f",
                   boost::bind( get0, _1 ),
                   boost::bind( get1, _1 )
               )
);
// outputs 10-23.40000012-24.400000
```

As you can see, overloaded function templates and `bind` does not get along very well...

Comment: Hi Luc! This is a super response. Never got so much insight on boost::tuple + template!

Answer (score 1):

Several problems here:
`eth_array` not defined, I'm guessing that should be _array.

```
v+= ( boost::make_tuple( 10,23.4) )( boost::make_tuple( 12,24.4) );
```

Here you are trying to call the tuple as a function? Maybe you tried something like:

```
v+=boost::make_tuple( 10,23.4);
v+=boost::make_tuple( 12,24.4);
```

Finally, what seems to be causing the issue you described:

```
boost::bind( eth_array::get<0>, _1 )
```

You should try using a function pointer instead of raw function name:

```
boost::bind( &eth_array::get<0>, _1 )
```

The complete body of main() that I got to compile and run:

```
int main( int argc, const char** argv ){

    using namespace boost::assign;
    typedef boost::tuple< int, double > _array;

    std::vector< _array > v;
    v+=boost::make_tuple( 10,23.4);
    v+=boost::make_tuple( 12,24.4);
    std::for_each( v.begin()
            , v.end()
            , boost::bind<int>(
                    printf
                    , "%d-%f\n"
                    , boost::bind( &_array::get<0>, _1 )
                    , boost::bind( &_array::get<1>, _1 )
             )
    );
}
```

Comment: Hi AndrzejJ. You are right I meant v+= boost::make_tuple( 10,23.4 ) , boost::make_tuple( 12,24.4 ); ( I did a bit of mess and I fixed my code to make it more readable ). 
The point is that boost::bind( &eth_array::get<0>, _1 ) still doesn't work in the std::for_each, even using the &. Still only for arg<1>

Comment: you don't have an eth_array type defined in your code, but when I used _array I got it to compile and run. I edited my answer to include the whole of main() function that compiles on my system.